# lw in MIPS (also a bit C)

Tags: c, assembly, mips

I have a homework question and it is troubling me.
It goes like

```
sll $t0, $s0, 2    // $t0 = $s0 << 2;

add $t1, $t0, $s2  // $t1 = $t + $s2;

lw  $s3, $0($t1)
```

I'm confused about the `$0`, does it have the same effect as 0?

What value would the result give?

It is a question asking me to translate mips into c, where $s0 is represented as variable name a, $s1 b, $s2 c etc.

The answer for this section is supposed to be `d = c[a];`,
but i really dont see why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In MIPS, `$0` or `$zero` is the 0th indexed and first register, and has value 0. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIPS_architecture#Compiler_register_usage).

Although that looks like a typo, since `lw` uses a 16-bit offset, which isn't the value from a register but rather a constant (recall that a register is 32 bits). So it should actually be `lw $s3, 0($t1)`.

The reason the code performs `d = c[a]` might seem simpler if I translate the MIPS into pseudo C-code:

```
$t0 = a*4
$t1 = $t0 + c (= c + a*4)
d = *(c + a*4)
```

So we end up loading into `d` the value in memory at location `c + 4a`, which is the base address of the array `c`, and the index of the element we want, `a`. We multiply by four because the type of the array is obviously a 4-byte long type, for example a 4-byte integer, so we need to jump `4*a` bytes from the beginning of the array to reach the appropriate point in memory.

Comment: oh it all make sense now!! I thought c as a normal value instead of address so cannot think up how the address of c pop out all out of a sudden. but yea after write in the pseudo C code form it become very clear to me now. Thank you a lot!